# Can I have multiple domain names point to different subdirectories on the same server

Tags: django, nginx, dns, webserver

I have two domain names `www.blog.com` and `www.project.com`

Currently, `www.blog.com/project` points to my project page.  I have nginx configured to redirect any requests to `/project` to my Django project.

I have just purchased `www.project.com`, and I would like it to display the same content as `www.blog.com/project` without it's URL changing in the browser. I'm not sure if there is a way to do this with DNS (a redirect won't preserve the URL), or a way to determine if a request came from `www.blog.com` or `www.project.com` at the server level.

In short:

1. `blog.com` stays pointing to root
2. `blog.com/project` needs keep being forwarded to Django
3. `project.com` now needs to appear in the browser bar and perform like 2.

Comment: This seems like it can be accomplished through an add-on domain. Now it's just a matter of configuring that...

Comment: Each domain is just a new `server` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for guidance.

Comment: I was slowly converging on that, thanks @RichardSmith!

Answer (score 0):

Richard Smith nailed it.  Creating a new server block was the way to go.  I've included the relevant parts of the .conf file in case anyone runs into this issue.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .project.com;


    # set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 2G;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress_http_access.log combined;


    #There were some shortsighted design decisions that meant it had to be
    # served from /project/ to avoid breaking a bunch of relative links.

    location = / {
        return 301 http://www.project.com/project/;


    }

    location /project/ {
            uwsgi_pass  django;
            include     /home/project/uwsgi_params;

    }
    # Django media
    location ^~ /project/media/  {
        alias /home/project/media/;  
            autoindex off;
}

location /project/static/ {
    alias /home/project/static/; 
    }
}
```